# Intent activity for Google places autocompleete collapses as soon as I start typing

Tags: android, android-intent, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to integrate the google places autocomplete using the intent activity. It opens just fine, but as soon as I start typing the activity retracts back down down.

There's not much code involved so I'm not sure, what could I be doing wrong?

```
    private fun initSearch() {
        val fields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

// Start the autocomplete intent.
        val intent =  Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields
        )
            .build(this.context!!);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data!!)
                val gmt = place.utcOffsetMinutes
                Log.d("place", "Place: " + place.name + ", " + place.id)
                Log.d("place", "offset: " + gmt)
            } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                val status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data!!)
                Log.d("place", status.statusMessage)
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.d("place", "canceled")
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a restriction with the wrong SHA-1 key. It's the one I use in production but now I am testing on the emulator so it didn't work. Once I've removed the restriction everything works fine.